# Field appearing NULL in tests

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I have a helper class that is working as intended while testing manually but in tests it is failing. I am trying to test the following method:

```
public class helper {
    @TestVisible
    private String getProperId(Case c)
    {
        if(c.Location__r.Proper_ID__c != null)
        {
            return c.Location__r.Proper_ID__c;
        } 
        else if(c.Account.Proper_ID__c != null)
        {
            return c.Account.Proper_ID__c;
        } 
        else 
        {
            return 'Error';
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the test method that is actually failing / receiving "Error".

```
@isTest 
public class helperTest {
    static TestMethod void getProperId(){
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.name = 'Unique Name';
        testAccount.Proper_ID__c = '123456789';
        insert testAccount;

        Case c = new Case();
        c.AccountId = testAccount.id;
        insert c;

        helper h = new helper();
        String properId = h.getProperId(c);
        System.assert(properId == '123456789'); // returning false
    }
}
```

The Id field is a Text field of length 50 and it must be unique. I have checked if it is unique in my Salesforce instance as well and it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I can see from your code you are accessing Cross-Object fields of Case.

You can only access Cross-Object fiels only when you query them.  Thus you have to query Case record's related object fields after dml to access them in helper

Your test class code will be.

```
@isTest 
public class helperTest {
    static TestMethod void getProperId(){
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.name = 'Unique Name';
        testAccount.Proper_ID__c = '123456789';
        insert testAccount;

        Case c = new Case();
        c.AccountId = testAccount.id;
        insert c;

        c = [Select Location__c,Location__r.Proper_ID__c,Account.Proper_ID__c   from Case where Id=:c.Id]

        helper h = new helper();
        String properId = h.getProperId(c);
        System.assert(properId == '123456789'); // returning false
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome!! I can't believe I missed that. That makes sense though, thanks for your quick reply. It worked now! (after an embarrassingly long time trying to figure it out on my own) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the `Account` lookup on your Case to `testAccount`, since the `Account` field is going to be null otherwise.

```
@isTest 
public class helperTest {
    static TestMethod void getProperId(){
        Account testAccount = new Account();
        testAccount.name = 'Unique Name';
        testAccount.Proper_ID__c = '123456789';
        insert testAccount;

        Case c = new Case();
        c.AccountId = testAccount.id;
        insert c;

        c.Account = testAccount;

        helper h = new helper();
        String properId = h.getProperId(c);
        System.assert(properId == '123456789'); // returning false
    }
}
```